# Python's `concurrent.futures` Threadpool- can be called by several functions

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, future, concurrent.futures

I'm looking to create a thread pool mechanism which will limit the number of threads in the system in any given time.
I have a several functions creating many threads and i want to create mutual thread pool for that.

From what i understood once a thread list is given to the future's threadpool it has to finish first since a 'with' statement must be used.

Can the futures module do that or do i have to write it myself?

Comment: You don't *need* to use a `with` statement to create a context manager: `ex = ThreadPoolExecutor(5)` will work just fine.

Comment: So when do I have to use the with statement with this module?

Comment: You don't ever *have* to. The with statement is used to guarantee that the pool will be shut down when you're done with it, but you're also able to manually call `ex.shutdown()` if the use-case calls for it.